# Have to restart lightdm when opening laptop lid after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04

I've just upgraded to 14.04.

Whenever I shut the laptop lid and come back to it later, after entering the password the screen just goes blank and requires `ctrl+alt+f2`-ing to a terminal to restart lightdm in order to get everything back working again.

I can't see anything obvious in the lightdm logs. I've deleted ~/.Xauthority as per the answer to a similar question to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this appears to be a bug in 14.04 release which prevents light locker from bringing the screen back up after a suspend when closing the lid.

In order to get your UI back up you will need to go to a text terminal `ctrl+alt+f1`, login and run

```
service lightdm restart
```

Unfortunately this will log you out and you will loose unsaved work.

To stop this happening in future, uninstall light-locker and light-locker-settings and make sure xscreensaver is installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove light-locker light-locker-extensions
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

I hope this helps. Hopefully this sill be fixed properly soon as there is a launchpad bug opened on it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1303736

Answer (score -1):

If you are booting windows 7 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS I had same problem then I tried everything referred from sites. Finally nothing worked for me.
So one thing worked for me.

1. Do not choose the default Ubuntu OS.
2. Click on advanced option for Ubuntu
3. Choose the OS option like "Ubuntu 16.04 .....(Systemed)"

This will boot your ubuntu os normally. and it works for me also it saves your time to everytime restart lightdm service.